# Make a list of numbers found in list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to construct a list in Prolog for every number it has found. For example, `findNumber([g,o,o,d,j,0,6],[0,6])`, but I can't construct the list with the given code:

```
isNum(6).
isNum(6).

findNumber([],[]).
findNumber([V|T],[-|TAfter]) :-
  isNum(V),
  findNumber(T,TAfter).
findNumber([H|T],[H|TAfter]) :-
  not(isNum(H)),
  findNumber(T,TAfter).
```

Please help... I am in quite the pickle. Thank you!

Comment: practically: `?- include(number, [g,o,o,d,j,0,6], Ns).`

Comment: @CapelliC  how do I do it for a list of list so if I had, Eg. [[g,o,o,d],[6,0,0,d]] => [6,0,0]? Is it possible to do it for multiple list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

You use a predicate `isNum` you define yourself, but only `6` seems to be a number. `0` is not a number? So correct this to:

```
isNum(0).
isNum(6).
```

or use [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog)'s builtin predicate [`number/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=number/1). (mind using `number/1` slightly modifies the semantics since `number/1` does not instantiate the given variable; as long as you use the predicate in only one direction - list to sublist - and do not use uninstantiated variables, that's fine however).

Secondly the predicate itself. First of all, you somehow swapped the cases: here it will add the `H` to the resulting list in the third clause (where `H` is not a number). Furthermore in the second clause you add a dash (`-`) to the list (this does not seem to be the desired behavior). A better predicate is therefore probably:

```
findNumber([],[]).
findNumber([H|T],[H|TAfter]) :-
  number(H),
  findNumber(T,TAfter).
findNumber([H|T],TAfter):-
  not(number(H)),
  findNumber(T,TAfter).
```

Or you can make the predicate more compact (and a bit faster) by using a cut (`!`):

```
findNumber([],[]).
findNumber([H|T],[H|TAfter]) :-
  number(H),
  !,
  findNumber(T,TAfter).
findNumber([_|T],TAfter):-
  findNumber(T,TAfter).
```

**Demo (`swipl`):**

```
?- findNumber([g,o,o,d,j,0,6],X).
X = [0, 6].

?- findNumber([g,o,0,o,d,j,6],X).
X = [0, 6].
```

## Recursive list structure

In case you want to do this recursively, you could do this by extending the predicate to a three arguments version `findNumber/3`. First we map the version with two arguments `findNumber/2` on `findNumber/3`:

```
findNumber(A,B) :-
    findNumber(A,B,[]).
```

(the previously defined predicate should be removed).

Next we define the following clauses:

```
findNumber([],TT,TT).
findNumber([H|T],[H|TA],TT) :-
  number(H),
  !,
  findNumber(T,TA,TT).
findNumber([H|T],TA,TT):-
  findNumber(H,TA,TL),
  !,
  findNumber(T,TL,TT).
findNumber([_|T],TA,TT) :-
    findNumber(T,TA,TT).
```

This works with a technique called *difference lists* which will be rather memory and cpu efficient. Furthermore the call stack will only grow in the number of levels of the given list.

The third argument specifies which value should be put at the tail of the list. Evidently the base case is that the list should end with a `[]` (that's what we do with the `findNumber/2` to `findNumber/3` conversion.

There is a special case in which Prolog will wonder whether there is a sublist (the second clause), it will call `findNumber/3` with the head of the list `findNumber(H,TA,TL)` and will generate a list `TA` leaving the tail `TL` open. The new tail `TL` will than later be filled with a call `findNumber(H,TL,TT)` (we thus will put our original tail `TT` at the real back, but need an intermediate tail `TL`).

**Demo (`swipl`)**:

```
?- findNumber([[g,0,0,d],[n,4,s,t,y]],K).
K = [0, 0, 4].

?- findNumber([[g,0,0,d],[n,4,[s,3,9],t,y]],K).
K = [0, 0, 4, 3, 9].
```

Comment: how do you change it for a list of list? So if you have a list for of, Eg. [[g,o,o,d],[6,0,0,d]] => [6,0,0]. How doI get the following?

Comment: @Tyler: do you mean recursively? Or is the number of levels limited to `2`?

Comment: I mean recursively until the list of list ran out. So when, Eg. [[g,o,0,d],[w,1,l,1]], is passed through as an input it will look for all the numbers for each list of list until there is no more list of list. Thus, it will print just a list [0,1,1].

Comment: the above solution didn't work for a list of list, like [[g,0,0,d],[n,4,s,t,y]]=>[0,0,4]. It said there was an error doing so.

Comment: @Tyler: well unfortunately I received no notification you modified your comment. The updated version should work.

Comment: thank you for you all your help and going through teaching me step by step I appreciate it! I just have one last problem, what if I'm trying to use this in another predicate? Such as, Eg. thisFunction(findNumber(List,X),X). List is would already be defined by thisFunction(List,Element).

Comment: @Tyler: predicates are *not equivalent* with functions. Unless you are using higher order predicates, you cannot use cascades of predicates. You can solve this for instance like `findNumber(X,Y), thisFunction(Y,X).`. A predicate has no *return value* in Prolog.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96432/discussion-between-tyler-and-commusoft).